# Query to get the previous value for a group of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Metadata with columns code,revno and idno. revno will be unique. Same idno may exist for multiple revisions. Now my requirement is, For a set of given revno, I need to query the previous revno uniquely if available as grouped.
Picture 1 contains data. if 3,4 & 7 are query revnos, then previous revno I need to get as in picture 2 as grouped. For 3 we get 1, because idno & code matches to it. For 4 we get null, because no previous data exists for idno 2 & code Person. For 7 we get 6 because, idno 2 & code Animal matches.

[image: Pic 2]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE to generate the highest `revno` prior to the current `revno` with the same `idno` and `code`, and then select the rows from the `CTE` which are the ones you want:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT revno, 
         LAG(revno) OVER (partition BY idno, code ORDER BY revno) AS prev
  FROM Metadata
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE revno IN (3, 4, 7)
ORDER BY revno
```

Output

```
REVNO   PREV
3       1
4       null
7       6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1d04979f0d7bda333d2fcacde53eadc)

Comment: thanks nick. tough query. need to understand this. :)

Comment: @Sreejesh.K.R. basically the CTE looks for the maximum value of `revno` in any rows with lower `revno` (that's what the `ROWS` part of the `ORDER BY` is for) that have the same `idno` and `code` (that's what the `PARTITION` is for). Then we filter based on the `revno` you wanted results for. You can't do that in the CTE because it will remove the rows that you want to find the previous value from.

Comment: @Nick I think the same could be achieved with just LAG analytic function, no need to provide the windowing clause

Comment: @micklesh I think you're right this is over engineered. You should post that as an answer

Comment: Thank you @Nick but I don't think this deserves a separate answer as it is a minor change: Instead of `MAX(revno) OVER (partition BY idno, code ORDER BY revno ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS prev` to use `LAG(revno) OVER (partition BY idno, code ORDER BY revno ) AS prev`.

Comment: @Sreejesh.K.R. apologies - as has been pointed out I over-complicated the original answer. I've updated now with something simpler.